# DMA buf import into Vulkan

Tags: linux, vulkan, dma, imx8

I am trying to import a DMA buffer I created with the DMA-buf heaps protocol into Vulkan. The DMA-buf is located in /cma-uncached memory. The chip is an i.MX8M Plus. I can mmap() the DMA-buf and it seems to be functioning correctly. I have attached the file descriptor for the DMA-buf to the VkDeviceMemory using vkImportMemoryFdInfoKHR. I then used vkBindBufferMemory to attach a VkBuffer to the VkDeviceMemory. Vulkan validation layers are not indicating any problems but the VkBuffer does not hold the data from the DMA-buf when I check with vkMapMemory. The portion of the code which attempts to import the DMA-buf into Vulkan is shown below. Please let me know if there is something obvious I am leaving out.

```
    VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfo extMemBufInfo{};
    extMemBufInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    extMemBufInfo.handleTypes = VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_DMA_BUF_BIT_EXT;
    extMemBufInfo.pNext = NULL;

    int FD_width = widthVIV;
    int FD_height = heightVIV;
    int size = FD_width * FD_height * 2;

    VkBufferCreateInfo bufferInfo{};
    bufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    bufferInfo.size = size;
    bufferInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT;
    bufferInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    bufferInfo.flags = 0;
    bufferInfo.pNext = &extMemBufInfo;

    if (vkCreateBuffer(device, &bufferInfo, nullptr, &fdBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        qDebug("failed to create buffer!");
    }

    VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
    vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(device, fdBuffer, &memRequirements);

    VkMemoryDedicatedAllocateInfo memDedAllocInfo{};
    memset(&memDedAllocInfo, 0, sizeof(memDedAllocInfo));
    memDedAllocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_DEDICATED_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    memDedAllocInfo.buffer = fdBuffer;

    VkImportMemoryFdInfoKHR importInfo{};
    memset(&importInfo, 0, sizeof(importInfo));
    importInfo.fd = dmafd;//expbuf.fd;//buf.m.fd;//dmabuffd;//heap_data.fd;// dmafd[0];
    importInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMPORT_MEMORY_FD_INFO_KHR;
    importInfo.handleType = VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_DMA_BUF_BIT_EXT;//VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD_BIT;//
    importInfo.pNext = &memDedAllocInfo;

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo{};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.allocationSize = memRequirements.size;
    allocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = findMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);
    allocInfo.pNext = &importInfo;

    if (vkAllocateMemory(device, &allocInfo, nullptr, &fdBufferMemory) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        qDebug("failed to allocate image memory!");
    }

    if(vkBindBufferMemory(device, fdBuffer, fdBufferMemory, 0) != VK_SUCCESS) {
          qDebug() << "vkBindBufferMemory failed: " << strerror(errno);
}
```

Comment: I would honestly be wary about trying to map memory that's allocated with `VkImportMemoryFdInfoKHR`.  That seems like a real corner case.  Have you tried just copying from that buffer to a host-visible buffer that was allocated normally?

Comment: My goal in importing the dma buffer is to avoid using CPU bandwidth to copy the data for each frame during live streaming. The frames are 4K at 30 fps. I can copy the data from the V4L2 buffers into a VkBuffer but I don't think this would work for our final product.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you use staging buffers typically, just to validate that the data is being exposed to the GPU properly.  Presumably you don't normally need it to be visible to the host for the normal use case, right?

Comment: OK, I understand your point better now. Yes, I have verified that I can use a staging buffer to get the frame data into the GPU, process it, and display it. You are correct that the data won't need to be visible to the host in normal use. One part of the process which I feel unsure of is that, when using a staging buffer, I call vkCmdCopyBuffer which references a VkCommandBuffer. But, aside from referencing, the DMA-buf bound VkBuffer in the VkDescriptorBufferInfo, I do not reference a VkCommandBuffer in any of the commands which act on the buffer.

Comment: I don't think you're getting what I'm saying.  My suspicion is that the imported DMA memory may not actually be mapping properly, so saying that your data isn't there might not actually be true.  As a test only, create a buffer that is host visible, and execute a single copy from the DMA associated buffer to your host visible buffer, then see if the expected data is in the host visible buffer when you map *that*.

Comment: You're right. I will try your original suggestion.

Comment: I created a new VkBuffer with the VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT and VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT properties. I used vkCmdCopyBuffer to copy my dma-buf associated buffer into this buffer and then memory mapped the new buffer. Unfortunately the results were the same as when I had previously directly memory mapped the contents of the dma-buf associated buffer.